# Error when trying to call a method: request for a member which is of a non-class type

Tags: c++, class, templates, gcc, compiler-errors

I got a class called "player" which I have to use in my project, it looks like this:

```
template<typename F>
class player {
public:
  int play(const F &field);
};
```

Now I want to use the function "play" in my Game and I tried calling it like this:

```
player<Game> player2();
player2.play(this);
```

I got the following error:

```
error: request for member 'play' in 'player2', 
which is of non-class type 'player<Game>()'
```

I have no idea why this is, I did similar things with other classes and it worked just fine ...
Could someone please help me? (I'm using eclipse and mingw gcc)

**Edit:**

Ok everything works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because player2 is being parsed as a function, I believe.

Comment: Change `player2()` to simply `player2`.

Comment: You've now asked a few quite different questions in the same page on StackOverflow :)

Comment: The 'undefined reference' error is a classic C++ problem when templates are involved.  Just search for "undefined reference c++ templates"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Undefined reference to" template class constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752837/undefined-reference-to-template-class-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
player<Game> player2();
```

Is a declaration of function `player2` that takes no arguments and returns `player<Game>` as value. change it to:

```
player<Game> player2;
```

Note, it worked for you before because you used constructors with parameters something like this:

```
Foobar foo( 123 );
```

In this case it cannot be interpreted as function declaration and works as intended.

EDIT:
method

```
int play(const F &field);
```

expects a const reference ot type F, what you are trying to pass is a pointer. You probably should dereference `this`:

player2.play( *this );

Comment: Furthermore he will have to dereference `this` for the types to match up. But one error message at a time...

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I changed ist to: player<Game> player2;  player2.play(this);
Now I get the following Error: "undefined reference to `player<Game>::play(Game const*)'"

Comment: @Ben `play` expects to get const reference you are trying to pass const pointer. I assume you need to put `*this` as parameter.

Comment: @Slava I made a little mistake before, that was the wrong error message. When using "*this" I actually got the same error as before when using "this": " undefined reference to `player<Game>::play(Game const&)' "    
I edited the code in my original Post

Comment: @Ben you have to implement function. As it is a template function it's implementation should be visible where you use it or you have to explicitly instantiate it.

Comment: Thx. Of course I implemented the fuction but maybe i did it wrong? I have a player.h and a player.cpp file. The code is in my first post, I edited it. I also tried to make an instance like this: player<Game>* player2 = new player<Game>();  but I still got Errors ("undefined reference to `player<Game>::play(Game const&)'")

Comment: @Ben you should read comments, not just half of it. Try to move implementation of play into header.

Comment: @Slava Oh I understood that wrong. Yeah, that worked, i didn't know you cant implement the function in a cpp-File. Now everything works fine. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to play needs to be of type Game not of type player.

```
Game myGame;
player<Game> player2;
player2.play(myGame);
```

Should work.

Comment: I actually call the fuction within the class "Game", but if I use "this" as an argument I get "undefined reference to `player<Game>::play(Game const*)'"

Comment: ok, you should use player2.play(*this); since "this" is a pointer to a Game object and not a reference to a game object, like "*this" is.