# I have no idea what this error means

Tags: c++

I compiled my code and this error message showed up in the terminal that I have no idea what it means.
Could someone explain or give me some hints?

```
/tmp/ccZ95DTV.o: In function `main': homework3_test.cpp:(.text+0x514):
undefined reference to `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&
apply<PowerN>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, PowerN)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Code:**

```
int test_power1, test_power2, test_power3;
PowerN power_three(3);
//test_power will now be 1
power_three(test_power1);
//test_power will now be 3
power_three(test_power2);
//test_power will now be 9
power_three(test_power3);
if (1 == test_power1) {
    std::cout<<"PowerN works for 3**0! +10\n";
    score += 10;
}
else {
    std::cout<<"PowerN failed on 3**0!\n";
}

if (3 == test_power2 and 9 == test_power3) {
    std::cout<<"PowerN works for 3**1 and 3**2! +10\n";
    score += 10;
}
else {
    std::cout<<"PowerN failed for 3**1 and 3**2!\n";
}

std::vector<int> test_power_v(3);
PowerN power_lessfour(-4);
//apply turns the vector into [1, -4, 16]
apply(test_power_v, power_lessfour);
std::vector<int> check_power_v;
check_power_v << 1 << -4 << 16;
if (test_power_v == check_power_v) {
    std::cout<<"Applying PowerN with -4 works! +10\n";
    score += 10;
}
else {
    std::cout<<"Applying PowerN with -4 failed!\n";
}
```

so what is added is the test code given by my instructor. If you want to see my implementation of the code,let me know.

so these line of code is my header file

```
template <typename T>
vector<int>& apply(vector<int>& v, T function);
```

and these are the implementation in the cpp file

```
template <typename T>
vector<int>& apply(vector<int>& v, T function) {
    for (vector<int>::iterator I = v.begin(); I != v.end(); ++I) {
        function(*I);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Thanks guys. I solve the issue. The template has to be defined in the header file, not the implementation file.

Comment: if u could share the code

Comment: could you show some code please?

Comment: You've probably spelled one of your variables/objects wrong when trying to call it. Post code!

Comment: You defined some function called `apply` and then implemented it, and the arguments don't match exactly the same. For example `template <class T> apply(vector<int>&, T);` and `template <class T> apply(vector<int>, T){...}` (Notice the missing ampersand)

Comment: You added more code, but not the code we need. Show the `apply` function definition and implementation.

Comment: Yeah, your implementation code is what is important. In particular, we need to see where the body of apply() is, because that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Based on your edit, the body of apply() seems correct. Is it in the _same cpp file_ as the first block of code you posted? If it's in a different cpp file, are you sure you told your compiler to build _both_ files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @TylerMcHenry  the first block of code I posted first was in a file where the main function is. Then the function is declared in a header file and actual implementation of it is in a different cpp file. I am sure while I compile it , I typed in command as "g++ -o o homework3.cpp homework3_test.cpp. Thank you for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Undefined reference to" template class constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752837/undefined-reference-to-template-class-constructor)

Comment: A related question, with another way to solve the problem: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you created a prototype for a function with the signature:

```
template <typename PowerN> vector<int> apply(vector<int>&, PowerN)
```

And you called it, but you never actually wrote a body for this function in any of the source that you asked your compiler to build.

Did you:

- Typo the name of this function when writing the body?
- Provide a slightly different signature for the function when writing its body (e.g. leave off an & or something)?
- Write the body in a different source file that you are not building?

Posting your code would help people to diagnose better.

Comment: Considering it's a template, it can't be in a different TU, either.