# Undefined reference to template class destructor

Tags: c++, templates

I had a problem with my template class Queue which I had been implementing the functions in a implementation file, so I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752837/undefined-reference-to-template-class-constructor) answer and resolved to do the implementation in the header file:

Queue.hpp

```
#ifndef QUEUE_HPP
#define QUEUE_HPP

#include "Instruction.hpp"
#include  "MicroblazeInstruction.hpp"

#include <memory>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class Queue{
public:
    Queue(unsigned int max): maxSize{max} {};
    ~Queue();

    std::list<T> getQueue(){
        return queue;
    };

    void push(T obj){
        if(queue.size() < maxSize){
            queue.push_front(obj);
        }
        else{
            queue.pop_back();
            queue.push_front(obj);
        }
    };

private:
    Queue(const Queue&);
    Queue& operator=(const Queue&);
    unsigned int maxSize;
    std::list<T> queue;
};


#endif
```

And I call this function from my main:

```
#include "icm/icmCpuManager.hpp"
#include "Instruction.hpp"
#include "MicroblazeInstruction.hpp"
#include "CpuManager.hpp"
#include "File.hpp"
#include "Utils.hpp"
#include "MbInstructionDecode.hpp"
#include "Queue.hpp"
#include "PatternDetector.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ...

    // Create pointer to microblaze instruction
    std::shared_ptr<MicroblazeInstruction> newMbInstruction;

    // Maximum pattern size
    const unsigned int maxPatternSize = 300;

    // Creating the Queue
    Queue<std::shared_ptr<MicroblazeInstruction>> matchingQueue(maxPatternSize);    

    ...
}
```

And I still have this compilation error:

```
# Linking Platform faith.exe
g++ ./CpuManager.o ./Instruction.o ./File.o ./Utils.o ./MicroblazeInstruction.o ./MbInstructionDecode.o ./PatternDetector.o ./main.o -m32 -LC:\Imperas/bin/Windows32 -lRuntimeLoader -o faith.exe
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x552): undefined reference to `Queue<std::shared_ptr<MicroblazeInstruction> >::~Queue()'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x83a): undefined reference to `Queue<std::shared_ptr<MicroblazeInstruction> >::~Queue()'
c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./main.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:24: recipe for target 'faith.exe' failed
make: *** [faith.exe] Error 1
```

I don't know why is this happening if I already specified the implementation functions in the header file, what do I have to do with the destructor?

Comment: Where did you implement `~Queue()`?

Comment: `~Queue()` does not appear to be defined. Did you define it?

Comment: That was the error, I did ~Queue(){}; but because I didn't do any changes in main it was still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
~Queue();
```

is not the same as

```
~Queue() {};
```

the second implements `~Queue`, the first just declares it.

You declared a `~Queue`, but defined it nowhere.  Your main destroys a `Queue`, which implicitly calls `~Queue`.  The linker tries to find it, finds it nowhere, and gives you an error.

Comment: It was that, I even did that but because I didn't do any changes with main it was compiling the same code as before.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there's a clear distinction between declaration and definition.  In your header file, the destructor ~Queue() is declared.  But the destructor ~Queue's definition is nowhere to be found.  The compile actually was successful but the linker will complaint if it can not find the implementation of your destructor in this case.