# Pass argument to function taking parent class argument without casting argument to parent class

Tags: c++, boost

I am building a Boost state machine. My state has a pointer to its own backend (`fsm`) to process events. All events of my state machine are children of an `MySatetMachineEvent` class (with an example child like `EventChild`). State transitions are only defined for children like `EventChild` of `MySTateMachineEvent`.
To clean up my code I want to create a function `processEvent(MySatetMachineEvent event)` taking all possible events. This class should then call the `process_event()` function with the passed event.
For example:

```
processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent event)
{
    fsm.process_event(event);
}
processEvent(EventCild());
```

should case a call of

```
fsm.process_event(EventChild());
```

Creating such a function causes the error that `fsm.process_event()` is called with an instance of `MyStateMachineEvent`. As written above there are no state transitions defined for this case.

This hinders my state machine from working in a proper manner, obviously.

---

So my question is if there is a way to pass any `EventChild` or other child of `MyStateMachineEvent` to my `processEvent(MySTateMachineEvent event)` function without casting the passed Object to `MyStateMachineEvent`.

---

I am aware of the solution to overlode my function like

```
processEvent(EventChild event) {
    fsm.process_event(event);
}
```

This would cause may functions (with the exact same line of code inside) in my case, thus i am looking for a cleaner and more fancy solution.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo has a good solution, but if there is no additional logic in `processEvent()`, why not just call `fsm.process_event()` directly? Is there more logic in `processEvent()`, or is the static type of the argument passed to `processEvent()` a `MyStateMachineEvent` (i.e. the type is not known at compile time)? If the latter, Vittorio's solution won't work and you need to look at `dynamic_cast<>` or refactor the design so that the events themselves know how to advance the state machine with their own `process_event()` member functions.

Comment: Actually the `fsm` thing needs to be accessed with `msm::back::state_machine<Statemachine> &fsm = static_cast<msm::back::state_machine<Statemachine> &>(*this);`. Thats the reason why I would like to create the function.

Comment: @CoffeeKangaroo Is there an `explicit` cast operator for the type of `this` to state machine? Otherwise, simply `/*...*/ &fsm = *this;` should do the trick as well (non-explicit cast operator or `this` inheriting from the class in question).

Comment: I stick to the boost guide for [msm](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html) with this line of code. Your suggested line does not work.
I guess there is a cast operator defined within the boost library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function template:

```
template <typename Event>
void processEvent(Event event)
{
    fsm.process_event(event);
}
```

Every instantiation will preserve the exact type of the `event` argument that was passed in.

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution more than the one pressented by [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312382/aconcagua).
To be honest I run also with this solution into a problem: the complier tells me that a reference to the specific usage of the template is missing. For example when I use the code given above with `something.porcessEvent(EventChild)` compliter gives mit the following error: `undefined reference to void processEvent<EventChild>(EventChild)`.

Comment: @CoffeeKangaroo Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)...

Comment: NOTE: the undefined reference is easy to solve, by moving everything into the header. It seams to be a common problem with templates. There are a lot of stackoverflow questions covering this problem: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752837/undefined-reference-to-template-class-constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Albeit I like [Vittorio Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo)'s [template approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53870995/1312382), it might not be suitable if you e. g. have some kind of event queue holding arbitrary events. A polymorphic approach could be more suitable then:

```
class MyStateMachineEvent
{
public:
    virtual ~MyStateMachineEvent() { }
    virtual void doOrGetSomething() = 0;
};

class EventChild : public MyStateMachineEvent
{
public:
    void doOrGetSomething() override;
};
```

Now your `processEvent` function might accept a reference, just as would the `fsm`'s variant as well:

```
void processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent& event)
{
    fsm.processEvent(event);
}

void FSM::processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent& event)
{
    // ...
    event.doOrGetSomething();
    // ...
}
```

And usage might look like this:

```
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<MyStateMachineEvent>> events;

events.emplace(new EventChild());

processEvent(**events.front());
events.pop();
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but as far as I got it your solution does not solve the problem since the actual class of the Object passed to the function `processEvent` is not guarded. There is still a cast to `MyStateMachineEvent`, or am I wrong?

Comment: Have a close look: I changed both functions to accept references. The important part is: References preserve the original type, although hidden away (they behave like pointers in this respect), so no, [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (as with the code in your question) will *not* occur.

Comment: @CoffeeKangaroo The trick is to use reference *or* pointer *instead of* passing by value: `processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent` **&** `event)` as well as `processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent` **\*** `event)` both do the trick wheras `processEvent(MyStateMachineEvent event)` does not.